# Consecutive prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Let's assume $k$ and $n$ are consecutive prime numbers, $k \lt n$.

An axiom: for any such $k$ and $n$, $k^2 \gt n$.

This seems "obviously" true to me, but could you please prove me wrong? Or if it is correct, could you please help me prove it?

Comment: Since $k \ge 2$, it follows that the next prime after $k$ must be less than $2k$, which in turn is less than or equal to $k^2$.  See [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate).

Comment: The problem statement vaguely resembles a famous unsolved problem, [Legendre's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture), that for each positive integer $n$, there exists a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is correct,  due to [Bertrand's Postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate) :

Primes occur no further intervals than $n$ and $2n$,   and $n^2>2n$ for $n>3$

Comment: Can't figure out why the link is broken, if anyone can fix?

Comment: done.${}{}{}{}$